# I can't compare password from my database and the one inputted

Tags: php

I am using php `crypt` function to make a password secure, but when I try and compare a password entered to a one in the database it will not work.

here is my code to create the password in the first place:

```
$crypt_password = crypt($_POST['confirm-password']);
```

here is me trying to compare to the password in another function:

```
$input_crypt_password = crypt($_POST['input-pw']);

if ($input_crypt_password == $dbpassword){
    // do change password function
}
```

This is not working.

when i print both passwords the are different.

why are the passwords different even though I am entering the same password and using crypt function on both?

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please read the documentation about the function you use. It will answer your question.

Comment: quick reference: `An optional salt string to base the hashing on. If not provided, the behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and can lead to unexpected results.`

Comment: Consider using the more secure password_hash() - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: The cause of this is likely a mistake in the code that stores the password into the database or a mistake in the table definition or both. You need to post that code.

Comment: try to remove any additional character like white space..  so before comparing use trim() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what to say that will add more detail than what everyone else has already said...

So, in modern day hash/unhashing algorithms it would be unsafe to store passwords using standard hashing functions (e.g. MD5 / SHA256) as it is quick and easy to unhash this type of entry.

`password_hash()` as referenced in other answers and comments should be you're #1 way to safely store passwords as it uses a **one way hashing algorithm**.

[You should read this page!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

And then in response to your original question, use `hash_equals()` function to compare passwords.

Answer (score 12):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

> Example #1 crypt() examples
>
> ```
> <?php
> $hashed_password = crypt('mypassword'); // let the salt be automatically generated
>
> /* You should pass the entire results of crypt() as the salt for comparing a
>    password, to avoid problems when different hashing algorithms are used. (As
>    it says above, standard DES-based password hashing uses a 2-character salt,
>    but MD5-based hashing uses 12.) */
> if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password))) {
>    echo "Password verified!";
> }
> ?>
> ```

The code in the question will effectively generate a new hash every time it's called - the existing password hash needs to be passed as the salt to get a consistent result.

As also mentioned in the docs:

> **Use of [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)() is encouraged**.

I'd go further and say you definitely should be using `password_hash` instead of calling `crypt` for password usage (assuming php >= 5.5); in any case though for whichever whatever tools/methods you're using - please read the docs to know how to use them.

Comment: learn the entire complications above for a inferior not-recommended password algorithm or simply use password password_hash as recommended by manual.

Comment: @bansi `password_hash() is a simple crypt() wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes. Use of password_hash() is encouraged.` I _also_ would encourage the use of `password_hash` but the error in the question is not "using the wrong function" it's "using a function, wrong" - or simply not reading the docs.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `crypt` directly for passwords.

If you have PHP 5.5+, than use the built in [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, otherwise if you have PHP 5.3.7+ use the [polyfill](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for this function.

Answer (score 2):

Try to something like this.

```
$crypt_password = crypt($_POST['confirm-password'],salt);

$input_crypt_password = crypt($_POST['input-pw'],salt);

if ($input_crypt_password == $dbpassword){
    // do change password function
    echo "Password match successfully!";
}
```

Here `salt` parameter to base the hashing on. If not provided, the behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

As many guys here said, you should use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) php function.

Here you can see a simple example how to use it:

```
<?php

$password = '123456';
$userInput = '123456';

$storedHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($userInput, $storedHash)) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'ERROR';
}
```

Also as mentioned before, if you use older version of PHP, you can install [polyfill](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

Did you trim the input before saving in db and while making the comparison. Since the input is coming from browser this may be a reason why it is not matching. otherwise this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41141338/1748066 seems appropriate.